# How to configure paypal payment method in opencart

Tags: paypal, opencart

How to configure paypal payment method in opencart?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administering the e-commerce solution which should be asked at it's forums directly or read at it's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below url it's may be help you

[Setup Paypal Payment methods](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/setting-up-payment-gateways/setting-up-payment-modules-in-opencart)